# Compile .ts without <reference...>

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, command-line-interface, tsc

Visual Studio can compile TypeScript project (even one file on save) without any `<reference>` tags.

Can I compile all *.ts files some way from command line (tsc.exe)? 
Simple, for edit TypeScript in WebStorm or in other IDEs.

Comment: I am using a single reference.ts file, which just contains the references to the .ts files. I am calling tsc on that (until i set up grunt-ts). tsc References.ts --out main.js --sourcemap --removeComments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. `tsc.exe` / `tsc` does not accept file globs. You can use an external tool to pass file globs through e.g. https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

Comment: The only alternative to this is to call `tsc` with the appropriate list of files, so grunt-ts is much, much easier than manually writing the `tsc` call.